# JavaEE: Best Practice for initial Data

Tags: jakarta-ee

I'm creating a JavaEE (plain JavaEE) web app. I've got some data that needs to be persisted the first time the server starts. The data needs to be written in a database if it doesn't exist.

I need to save PermissionGroups and an initial user with the root-permission-group.

What is the best practice for that?

(I'm using the latest java-version, wildfly web server and h2db)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to add huge amounts of data, use

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class AppInitSingleton {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // add here using ejbs, ....
    }
}
```

The @Startup annotation tells the application server to initialize the singleton directly (call @PostConstruct)